# Mysql 8 install problems

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to upgrade to mysql 8 but getting the following. I have no clue what to do from here. I'm not seeing much information on what error to investigate. It says it's installed but when I try to start it I get the same errors.

```
root@server:~# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libevent-core-2.1-6 libfcgi-perl libhtml-template-perl
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-03-27 08:15:16 EDT; 6ms ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 26739 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 26691 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26739 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"

Mar 27 08:15:13 websvr systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Mar 27 08:15:16 websvr systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 27 08:15:16 websvr systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 27 08:15:16 websvr systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                        :
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem after searching the logs. It was just a bad variable in the config file